# FadeIn does not work on Load function

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a question about Jquery fadein. I am trying to use it on a div, but it does not work, even not when hiding it first.

I am using this code which fills the DIV when loading the page:

```
$('#pagebody').html('<p><img src="/common/images/loader.gif" width="24" height="24" /></p>');
$('#pagebody').load("useradmin.php").hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

First it loads a little preloader image, then it loads the contents of the div, which i want to fade in. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: That code will fadein #pagebody. is #pagebody a DIV? And what is the purpose of hide() ? Do you want to load the contents of useradmin.php and then hide it - then fade it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load()` is asynchronous - in this case it means that `.hide().fadeIn()` will be executed before the load is complete. Put the fadeIn to a callback function that will execute *after* the content has loaded:

```
$('#pagebody').load("useradmin.php", function() {
    $( this ).hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this.

```
 $('#pagebody').html('<p><img src="/common/images/loader.gif" width="24" height="24" /></p>').load("useradmin.php", function(){
       $('#pagebody').hide().fadeIn('slow');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pagebody').load('useradmin.php', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

That should work...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the question, but I'm guessing it would be a good idea to wait until the content is loaded before doing any fading ?

```
$('#pagebody').hide()
   .html('<p><img src="/common/images/loader.gif" width="24" height="24" /></p>')
   .load("useradmin.php", function() {
       $(this).fadeIn('slow');
   });
```

On another note, `load()` will replace the content that was added with `html()`, so the `<p>` and `<img>` element you add with html() is overwritten by the content in useradmin.php, but since it's a preloader, I'm guessing that is the intended effect ?